# Auto Sort Looker Studio Table Rows, based on latest updated row

Tags: looker-studio

- Looker Data studio is connected to a Google Sheet.
- The Google sheet rows are updated randomly.
- The table in Data studio reflects values in Google Sheet rows
  Question. :- Can the Looker studio table rows be auto sorted when it updates itself with Google sheet, to bring the latest updated row on the top of the table

Couldnt find any setting to do so , can it be done programmatically and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to have one column within the sheet with an apps script behind which updates a timestamp whenever a change happens within that specific row. I think once you have that column of timestamps its pretty much straight forward from there on to use that column in studio `sort` option.